# Play Framework generated one table for two Many To Many relations

Tags: jpa, playframework, many-to-many, ebean, playframework-2.2

A fragment from my Game.java:

```
@Entity
public class Game extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Checkpoint> visitedCheckpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Checkpoint> answeredCheckpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();
}
```

In the automatic SQL evolution, Play created just one many-to-many relationship table: `game_checkpoint`, with just two columns being foreign keys: `game_id` and `checkpoint_id`. That leads to an error: I add a visited checkpoint, but then I can't add the same checkpoint as answered, because of primary key constraint violation.

How to force Play to generate SQL with two tables: `game_visitedcheckpoint` and `game_answeredcheckpoint` so later I can manipulate the two Checkpoint lists separately?

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by defining tables' names explicitly:

```
@Entity
public class Game extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public User user;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="game_visitedcheckpoint")
    public List<Checkpoint> visitedCheckpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="game_answeredcheckpoint")
    public List<Checkpoint> answeredCheckpoints = new ArrayList<Checkpoint>();
}
```